# I can not install my Android app to my phone

Tags: java, android

I am new in android app development. 
I made an android app. When I run it from Android Studio to my phone it works perfectly. 
Then I back it up to my SD card and try to install it and it gives me an  "Installation failed" message.
I tried using various phones but it didn't work.

What is the problem actually? 
What should I do to install my app on other phones (regarding the SDK version)?

Comment: You need to check the installation exception and stack trace?

Comment: If your phone has google play service, sometime, the application installation fail when you are not installing it from `google play store`.

Comment: @AK47 , thank you for your comment!
 I'm new in this platform, so i'm not familiar with those term you used.
Could you please explain how to check those?

Comment: I checked for "install from unknown sources" from settings @ODxNorm

Comment: @Amine116 they are among the first things to learn about before starting to program apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build APK file to run the app on different devices and take a backup. The debug file can't be backed up and shared with other devices. The steps of how to build an APK file are given below. Please follow steps and it will work as you expect.

[image: The process to build APK file]

[image: The process to locate the generated APK file]

[image: This is where the APK file is available]

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Your answer was perfectly correct and working on my device. 
It was easy and working <3 

I will let you know if it work all other devices.

Comment: Welcome brother. Happy programming. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to install your app via usb  then u have to open a developer option and inside the developer option you have to on usb tethering and install via usb option

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog *Generate Signed Bundle or APK* set checkbox `V1 (Jar Signature)` and `V2 (Full APK Signature)`.